# Checkout current step callback

Tags: checkout, magento2.3

Is there a callback that can be used (where a mixin can be added) for when a checkout step is displayed?
For example, there is the `navigate` function for each step that is called when the checkout is loaded directly to that step.
So if you access directly the url `checkout/#some-step` and there is a step with the code `some-step` then the function `navigate` from that step js file is called.

Is there similar for when a step becomes active?
Note: need this for a custom step, so I can change the code in that step without restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the way to go, but it seems to work for me.
I added a subscriber on the `isVisible` observable method:

```
 isVisible: ko.observable(false),
 initObservable: function () {
     this._super();
     this.isVisible.subscribe(function (value) {
         if (value) {
            //if value is true, it means the step just became visible.
            //I placed my logic here
         }                              
     }, this);
     return this;
 },
```